# Error Message: CA1001 - Error Message: Form Creates IDiposable Types

Tags: c#, forms, dispose, using, idisposable

Visual Studio is Complaining about my way to Close and Dispose of a Form (after I'm done with it).
The way I do it; Visual Studio tells me that:

i.e: "Form1 Creates IDisposable Types".

I’ve tried implementing using statement, but the Form won't stay open, and everything is disposed at the end of the loop.
Even though with „using“ statement; visual studio reports the same message.

How should one Properly Implement this?

Example with Using:

```
private void OpenForm1()
{
   // Create a new instance of Form1
   using (var f1 = new Form1())
   {
      // Some Code Here
   }
   // Form1 Instance Gets Disposed at the End of the Loop Above.
}
```

An example of my Current (modest) Open & Close Form Method:

Small Note: I'm calling this method bellow from a class that will control:

- Open & Close Forms
- Data passed through Forms

  ```
  private Form1 f1;

  public void OpenForm1(bool _Open, int _LocX, int _LocY)
  {
      try
      {
          switch (_Open)
          {
              case true:

                  // Close & Dispose "Form1" (if Opened)
                  if (f1 != null) { OpenForm1(false, 0, 0); }

                  // Re-Open Form1 with New Data (if Closed)
                  if (f1 == null) { f1 = new Form1(_LocX, _LocY); }

                  f1.Show();
                  break;

              case false:
                  if (f1 != null) { f1.Close(); f1.Dispose(); f1 = null; }
                  break;
          }
      }

      catch (InvalidOperationException _IOE) { MessageBox.Show(_IOE.Message); }
  }
  ```

Comment: That `OpenForm` method is quite complicated for what it does. It relies on the side-effects of recursively calling itself to work, and despite its name it can be used to *close* a form as well. Just create a matching `CloseForm` method. As for that error, what's the specific error code? CA1001? CA1063? Or something else? It may just be complaining that you're not disposing `f1` in `Form1`'s `Dispose` method, so it cannot guarantee that it's always being disposed (even if you always do, elsewhere).

Comment: Greetings Pieter; It's Displaying CA1001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only use `using` when your variable's lifetime ends when your using block falls out of scope.  You want your Form to live on past the point where it falls out of scope of the `using` statement, so you should not use a `using` block there.

`Form.Close` calls `Dispose` anyway, so you don't have to worry about it here as the closing of the form will handle resource cleanup.  The only time you have to call `Dispose` on a form is if you never called `Show`.

Comment: Thanks Hoodaticus. That enlightened me a little bit. However the "IDiposable Types" message still remains. This means I'm not doing this properly. Even though I call Close or Dispose.

Comment: @Richard - that warning comes from having an IDisposable field in a class that doesn't implement IDisposable.  Implement IDisposable and you are good.  It doesn't even have to do anything.

Comment: @Richard - the idea here is that a class has a responsibility to dispose all of its own internal state, namely, its fields, if it is necessary to do so.  That way you can construct large trees of IDisposables and only need to call Dispose on the root of the tree to clean up the whole thing.